# How do I show there exist $k \in [0,n]$ such that $\| f_k(y)-x\|< \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a bounded and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Let $f: X \rightarrow X $ be a homeomorphism. Write $f_n$ for the nth iterate of $f$ if $n>0$, for the $-nth$ iterate of $f^{-1}$ if $n<0$, and the identity map if $n=0$. Thus, $f_{n+1}(x)=f(f_n(x))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Write $A(x)=\{f_n(x):n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for $x \in X$. Suppose that $A(x)$ is dense in $X$ for all $x \in X$.

Show that for each $x \in X$ and all $\epsilon >0$, there exist $n>0$ such that for all $y \in X$, there exists $k  \in [0,n]$ such that $\| f_k(y)-x\|< \epsilon$.

Anyone suggest some direction to solve this question?

Comment: Is $X$ just bounded or compact?

Comment: X is bounded and closed.

Comment: The proof is easy if $f$ is an isometry, but I have a hard time in general. I use uniform continuity by I get $\delta$ to depend on $n, \epsilon$ and $n$ to depend on $\delta$.

Comment: Is the difficulty with $k\geq 0$, or with $k$ being bounded? The question seems to imply that $\left\{f_n(x): n\geq 0\right\}$ is also dense in $X$.  In addition, no $f_n$ other than $f_0$ can have a fixed point; otherwise, $A(x)$ would be finite (and therefore not dense in $X$, assuming $X$ is infinite) for some $x$. This further implies that $f_n$ (and therefore $f_{-n}$) can't be a contraction mapping for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Just some ideas.

Comment: @N.S. Could you give an idea of your proof when $f$ is an isometry? Since a function that is 1-Lipschitz over a compact admits a fixed point $x$ for which $A(x) = \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$ I think this solution works only if $X$ has a unique element.

Comment: @blamethelag Done. Note though that you need $f$ to be $1- \epsilon$-Lipshitz for Banach fixed point theorem to apply. More importantly, the function in your example fails the assumptions: ". Suppose that $A(x)$ is dense in $X$ for all $x\in X$."

Comment: What is not clear to me is if there exists $X \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ compact and an isometry $f : X \to X$ such that for each $x \in X$ the set $A(x)$ is dense.Without the restriction $X \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ I think there are many examples of minimal dynamical systems which satisfy these conditions.

Comment: @N.S. For examples one can take $X$ to be any round circle in any 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$, and one can take $f$ to be any irrational rotation of that circle.

Comment: @LeeMosher How did I miss that:)

Comment: Have yu tried proof by contradiction? Negate the stated claim and seems like it becomes easy to refute the negation!

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment, requested by OP.**

Assume that $f$ is an isometry, and that $X$ is bounded (but not necessarily closed).

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, by a simple compactness of closure argument, we can find $F=\{y_1,...,y_k \} \subseteq X$ so that for all $z \in X$ there exists some $1 \leq j \leq k$ with
$$
\|z-y_j \|_\infty < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \qquad (*)
$$

Since by assumption $A(x)$ is dense in $X$, for each $1 \leq j \leq k$ there exists some $n_j \in \mathbb Z$ so that
$$
\|f_{n_j}(x)-y_j\| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
Since $f$ is an isometry, this is equivalent to
$$
\|x-f_{-n_j}(y_j)\| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} \qquad (**)
$$

Now, pick $M,N \in \mathbb N$ so that $-M \leq n_j \leq N$ for all $1 \leq j \leq k$.
Set $n=N+M$. We claim that this $n$ works.

Let $y \in X$ be arbitrary. Since $f_{M}(y) \in X$, by (*) there exists some $1 \leq j \leq k$ so that
$$
\|f_{M}(y)-y_j \| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

Since $f$ is an isometry we get
$$
\|f_{M+n_j}(y)-f_{n_j}(y_j) \| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
and hence by (**)
$$
\|f_{M+n_j}(y)-x \| <\epsilon
$$
Since $0=M+(-M) \leq M+n_j \leq M+N=n$ this proves the claim.

Comment: It doesn't seem plausible for $f$ to be an isometry, since $X$ likely does not have infinite symmetries.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry It is possible for $f$ to be an isometry, as the comment by Lee Mosher shows.

Comment: Yes, that's the example I had in mind, but it's an enormous constraint to add to the original problem unless it follows from the other assumptions.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry I agree that this is a big constraint, that's why I originally mentioned this as a comment. I only posted this because someone asked me to.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe you can extend it to any $X$ that has the *same topology* as a sphere of some dimension. Then there should be a homeomorphism that takes $X$ to that sphere and $f$ to an isometry on that sphere, with distance expansion bounded in both directions due to the compactness of $X$.